# Cannot link xml layout in android when click button

Tags: android, button, linker

I'm very new in android and i am working on a app.
I meet problem in linking the 2nd page to the 3rd page while clicking the button. I had tried to solve the problem but it do not work. Below is my AndroidManifest.xml
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fyp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".BelajarActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">

        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".KnamaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

below is BelajarActivity.java

```
package com.example.fyp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class BelajarActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.belajar);

        Button bnama = (Button) findViewById(R.id.knama);
        bnama.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent namaIntent = new Intent(BelajarActivity.this,KnamaActivity.class);
                startActivity(namaIntent);
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Post your logcat trace

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. But please include Logcat output if any exception is being raised.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
        bnama.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { //this is wrong

          ...
        });
```

should be

```
     bnama.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
..
});
```

OnClickListener should be of type View

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line

```
bnama.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```